# Any way to reorder photos on 500px?

Tags: photos, 500px

I've been uploading some of my better photos to [500px](http://500px.com/), and thought I'd order my photos by preference, but I can't find any way to do that. Is it not possible?

Comment: Is this still in persuit or was it a dead end?

Comment: I believe this is now possible in the "Sets" feature available to paying customers. Since I've moved back over to Flickr for most of my photo uploading needs, I no longer have a strong interest in this, but if somebody would write a (current) definitive answer it might certainly help others. @Bjoern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Currently there is no option to reorganize the images on your public profile, only within your portfolio can you drag & drop images to the order you like. We will be introducing an option to re-arrange and categorize your work, it is coming very soon.
>
> Samantha
> Customer Support
> 500px.com

From [their Support Center](http://support.500px.com/customer/portal/questions/151127-photo-display-order).

Comment: Thanks. Since that was posted quite recently, I'm pretty optimistic that it will actually be implemented soon.